# Java - DocumentBuilder closing Socket connection

Tags: java, sockets, connection

I have a problem with a `Socket` connection closing too fast. I was told I need to temporarily load data from the `Socket` and the parse it. Here is my code:

```
ServerSocket listen = new ServerSocket(this.port);
Socket server;

while(i < this.maxConnections)
{
    server = listen.accept();
    processRequest(server);
    i++;
}
```

### processRequest

```
protected void processRequest(Socket server) throws IOException
{
    ProcessXML response = new ProcessXML(server.getInputStream());

    new PrintWriter(server.getOutputStream(), true).println("response text");
}
```

### processXML

```
public ProcessXML(InputStream is)
{
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setValidating(false);
    factory.setNamespaceAware(false);

    Document doc = factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new InputSource(is));
    ....
}
```

## error

```
[Fatal Error] :2:1: Premature end of file.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
at ProcessXML.<init>(ProcessXML.java:22)
at Bank.processRequest(Bank.java:41)
at Bank.listen(Bank.java:25)
at BankStart.main(BankStart.java:6)
```

---

Now I could store content of `server.GetInputStream()` into a file and then supply that to `DocumentBuilder`, but I think its a bad solution. How could I store content to some temporary storage and also be able to supply that to `.parse()` without closing the socket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the solution you are using expects the data to be avaible at construct time. You would need to use a stream parser. find a STAX implementation and you should be able to do this

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem like a socket thing... Otherwise you'd see a socket closed exception or something like that. As a test just read the bytes and save it to a text file somewhere, don't worry about building the doc just yet. Check that the file is a properly formed XML and that the encoding matches that specified in the document. Look for any funny characters at the end of the file, could be that the client is inserting some weird EOF character or similar.

Comment: Actually I solved the problem. I simply loaded whole InputStream into String via Scanner and I just supplied that to DocumentBuilder...

Answer (score 0):

Write yourself a derived class of `FilterInputStream` that ignores `close()` and wrap the socket input stream in that before supplying it to `DocumentBuilder.parse().`